# How to use a specific proxy on EXIT node?

Tags: address

I would like to know, if there is any way to use a proxy at exit of TOR? I have read a lot of manuals, how to set up exit nodes for a specific country, but that is not what I need. I need to visit a site with a transparent proxy server, but it is not safe enough just to set up the proxy in regular browser. I need to access the site trough the Tor, then into the specific proxy server, and through that server to the targeted website. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understood you right. Do you want something like browser->entry node->middle node->exit node->proxy->website or  browser->proxy->entry node->middle node->exit node->website?

Comment: I just opened Tor Browser and went through a proxy to a website and everything worked ok so I would say yes